# fs.createReadStream(path[, options]) - What are those options?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

According to Node's v6.10.2 API - options is an object or string with the following defaults:

```
{
flags: 'r',
encoding: null,
fd: null,
mode: 0o666,
autoClose: true
}
```

But I've seen highWaterMark property being used to set Buffer size. But API didn't put it on the option. So I'm wondering is there more options that API didn't write on the document. If so where I can find the full option list?

And API didn't talk about flags, So I would like to know what flags dose in this case and what's the difference between

```
flags: r
flags: w
flags: r+
```

I tried to find those answer but I didn't find any helpful information. I would really appreciate if somebody help me to understand this topic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer the explanation in streams context still seem to be missing from the documentation, so it's unclear as to what options there can be for a readable stream. As far as I can tell the flags are most likely the same flags as specified for other fs operations like fs.open.

From the docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

`r` - Open file for reading. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.

`r+` - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.

`rs+` - Open file for reading and writing in synchronous mode. Instructs the operating system to bypass the local file system cache.

This is primarily useful for opening files on NFS mounts as it allows skipping the potentially stale local cache. It has a very real impact on I/O performance so using this flag is not recommended unless it is needed.

`w` - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).

`wx` - Like 'w' but fails if path exists.

`w+` - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).

`wx+` - Like 'w+' but fails if path exists.

`a` - Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist.

`ax` - Like 'a' but fails if path exists.

`a+` - Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it does not exist.

`ax+` - Like 'a+' but fails if path exists.